# Displaying junit fail messages through maven2

Tags: maven-2, junit, surefire

I have a Java project that is built through maven2.  We use JUnits and occasionally have test failures.  I'm wondering if there is a way to display more information when the test fails.  When I run the tests through IntelliJ I get something like "Expected: 3  Actual: 10."

Is there a way to get this same data through maven?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) to output more information on the console using the [`useFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#useFile) option.

Your configuration would look like this, then:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <useFile>false</useFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you need this for specific invocations of your build you can also set this parameter via the command line, like so:

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.useFile=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: [Maven Surefire Report Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/show-failures.html)?

And of course the test results are available in `target/surefire-reports`, but the format is far from human-readable. Also your CI server should display test failures in a decent format.